# Maximum output of HKDF

Tags: hkdf

I got a question with the RFC of HKDF https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869.

There is a maximum specified for the output keying material. The length of the OKM shall be <= 255*HashLen. What does it mean? For example there is a hashfunction with output of 32 byte. Is my maximum OKM then 255*32 = 8160 Byte? Or does it mean, my maximum repetition in the loop is smaller or equal than 8160? So that would mean, that you can generate 8160 (rounds) * 32 (per round output) 261120 Byte output.

I am a little bit confused...thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

The former. Maximum output must be <= 255*HashLen. So for SHA256 which has a digest of 32 bytes, max HKDF output would be <= 8160 bytes. For SHA512 which has a digest of 64 bytes, max output must be <= 16320 bytes. I can't imagine you would need a key longer than 8160 bytes. If you require multiple keys you can use the 'info' parameter for different contexts/keys from the same PRK.

Comment: That last sentence scored an instant +1 from my side. I would also use a specific info parameter for an for a deterministic IV, in case one needs to be derived from the master key material. *Note that e.g. in hardware tokens you often need to explicitly derive each key. In software you can just split a byte string, but try to do the same in a Cryptoki (PKCS#11) implementation and you'll run into problems.*